# adding multiple playlist entries is unreliable

Tags: youtube-api, playlist, json-c

I'm seeing issues where adding multiple entries to a playlist in a short amount of time seems to fail regularly without any error responses.

I'm using the json-c format with version 2.1 of the api. If I send POST requests to add 7 videos entries to a playlist then I see results of between 3-5 of them actually being added to the playlist.
I am getting back a 201 created response from the api for all requests.

Here's what a request looks like:

```
{"data":{"position":0,"video":{"duration":0,"id":"5gYXlTe0JTk","itemsPerPage":0,"rating":0,"startIndex":0,"totalItems":0}}}

and here's the response:

{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"PLL_faWZNDjUU42ieNrViacdvqvG714P4QjvSDgGRg1kc","position":4,"author":"Lance Andersen","video":{"id":"5gYXlTe0JTk","uploaded":"2012-08-16T19:27:19.000Z","updated":"2012-09-28T20:20:39.000Z","uploader":"usanahealthsciences","category":"Education","title":"What other products does USANA offer?","description":"Discover USANA's other high-quality products: the Sens skin and hair care line, USANA Foods, the RESET weight-management program, and Rev3 Energy.","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5gYXlTe0JTk/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/5gYXlTe0JTk/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gYXlTe0JTk&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=5gYXlTe0JTk"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/5gYXlTe0JTk?version=3&f=playlists&d=Af8Xujyi4mT-Oo3oyndWLP8O88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDm&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CkgLENy73wIaPwk5JbQ3lRcG5hMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHNyIQH_F7o8ouJk_jqN6Mp3Viz_DvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v7.cache7.c.youtube.com/CkgLENy73wIaPwk5JbQ3lRcG5hMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHNyIQH_F7o8ouJk_jqN6Mp3Viz_DvPB7EI6RNWvHdRsUJxg5gw=/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":72,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":5.0,"likeCount":"6","ratingCount":6,"viewCount":1983,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":0,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}},"canEdit":true}}
```

The problem doesn't change if I set the position attribute.

If I send them sequentially with a 5 second delay between them then the results are more reliable with 6 of the 7 usually making it on the playlist.
It seems like there is a race condition happening on the api server side.
I'm not sure how to handle this problem since I am seeing zero errors in the api call responses.

I have considered doing batch processing, but can't find any documentation on it for the json-c format.  I'm not sure it that would make a difference anyways.

Is there a solution to reliably adding playlist entries to a playlist?

Comment: Do the videos ever get added to the playlist (after a delay of X minutes)? Or is it like the requests are just ignored despite getting back a HTTP 201?

Comment: The majority of cases the videos appear to never make it to the playlist.

Comment: I am seeing similar problems when removing multiple videos from a playlist as well. Not sure if it's related, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Okay, I'll file a bug with the API engineering team. I might need to ping you guys for more debugging data, though.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the same as http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3005, right? I'll follow up there.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in and update to the youtube data apis around the 25th of October.